# div tag does not appear on the webpage

Tags: html, css

I seem to be having a slight problem here. My divs dont show up in the web page. I tried changing the position of the div to absolute but it still dosen't show  up.

Here is my code:

```css
body {
  background: url("http://fux-media.com/yz/skyline_exp1.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.header {
  background-color: #DADAC8;
  width: 900px;
  height: 10%;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 7px;
  margin-top: -100px;
  margin-left: 170px;
  z-index: 500;
}
img {
  border-radius: 70%;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin-left: 40%;
  height: 175px;
  width: 175px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4118/4890853985_b34231ccfb_o.jpg" />
<div class="header"></div>
```

Comment: Well I see your div :) but you have to put some content in: http://jsfiddle.net/9myL7kLe/

Comment: The div has `height: 10%`, but there is no height to inherit! 10% of 0 = 0 :). If you want to use a percentage height, place a height on the html and body, like so: `html,body { height: 100%; }`

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. Use [a validator](http://validator.w3.org).

Answer (score 1):

I've converted your example code into a code snippet and it seems to work fine. What exactly seems to be wrong? Are you missing the `.header` `<div>`? In that case give it some content or give it a fixed width. How should the `.header` look?

```css
body {
  background: url("http://fux-media.com/yz/skyline_exp1.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.header {
  background-color: #DADAC8;
  width: 900px;
  height: 10%;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 7px;
  margin-top: -100px;
  margin-left: 170px;
  z-index: 500;
}
img {
  border-radius: 70%;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin-left: 40%;
  height: 175px;
  width: 175px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4118/4890853985_b34231ccfb_o.jpg" />
<div class="header"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

in your css add this

```
html, body { height: 100%; width: 100%; margin: 0; }
```

Comment: it seems to have worked. i almost forgot about this. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your div is present there. But it doesn't have any contents that's why it is not visible.
Add some content in it like text etc. or add some padding to the 'header' class. Then you will be able to see it.